# React Native ScrollView is not scrolling (we think the issue is not with the render but something above it)

Tags: react-native

We are trying to make the screens of our app scrollable and were able to get it to work for all of our screens except one. Weirdly enough, even when we replaced everything in our render function with many different scrollview tutorials including facebooks tutorial (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-scrollview) (making sure we had correct imports and stylistic things like flex), our screen would not scroll.

Here's our code:

```
    //a bunch of imports including:
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {ScrollView} from 'react-native'
    class TutorialScreenNew extends Component {

        state = {
         //a bunch of states
        }


        async componentDidMount() {
          // waits for tensorflowjs to be loaded and ready

        })

        this.model = await mobilenet.load()

       this.setState({ isModelReady: true })
       this.getPermissionAsync()
       }


     getPermissionAsync = async () => {
      //some code
   }

   imageToTensor(rawImageData) {
     //some code
   }

   classifyImage = async () => {
     //some code
    }

   pickAndClassifyImage = async () => {
      //some code
     }

   renderPrediction = prediction => {
      return (
          <Text key={prediction.className} style={styles.getStartedText}>
            {prediction.className}
          </Text>
       )
    }

   handleCommon = (text) => {
      this.setState({ common: text })
   }
   handleScientific = (text) => {
      this.setState({ scientific: text })
   } 
   submit = (common, scientific) => {
      //some code
   }

    render() {

       //some lets

      //some conditionals
      return(
      <ScrollView
          style={styles.container}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>

         {!predictions && !isStatusReady && (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              //content
          </View>
          )}
         {predictions && !isStatusReady && (
         <View style={styles.container}>
            //content
         </View>
          )}
         {predictions && isStatusReady && (
         <View style={styles.container}>
            //content
         </View>
         )} 

       </ScrollView>
    );  
 }
 }
 //also this is the container
 container: {
     flex: 1,
     flexGrow: 1,
     paddingTop: 20,
     paddingBottom: 10,
     backgroundColor: '#003308',
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue: We were using tab navigation and for whatever reason having two screens in our stack prevented scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be normal, Scroll view will be visible only when content exceeds the height of your device, I have added a code to demonstrate that case, Please try that

```
class TutorialScreenNew extends Component {

  ...........

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sampleText : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque egestas efficitur sodales. Curabitur non massa leo.'
    }
  }


  .........
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>

        <ScrollView
          style={styles.container}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>

          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.state.sampleText}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.state.sampleText}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.state.sampleText}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.state.sampleText}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.state.sampleText}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.state.sampleText}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.state.sampleText}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.state.sampleText}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.state.sampleText}</Text>
          </View>


        </ScrollView>

      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexGrow: 1,
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#003308',
 },
});
```

Comment: No thats not the issue. The reason we need scrollview is because all of our content is not being shown. (I tried your sample just to confirm but it didn't work). Also, in case is helpful, scrollview works on ios but not on web

Comment: The above code works on angroid app for sure (Please add an outer view with flex : 1), what you mean by web ? can you please make it clear, so I can help you to figure out the issue, Thank you :)

Comment: So the code scrolls on the ios emulator and on android but not on the web browser (we are using expo and there are three options: run on android emulator, ios simulator, or web browser). Also adding an outer view with flex 1 doesn't do anything :(. We tried that (we also tried wrapping everything inside the scrollview with a view tag of flex 1 based on another stackoverflow post but that didn't work either).

Comment: I really think the issue isn't with anything inside our return but something else because we have similar code in one of our other screens that scrolls properly.